# Uncaught ReferenceError with redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

T'm trying to use redux-saga module.

However I have following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at eval (saga.js:5)
    at Object../js/sagas/saga.js (saga.js:393)
    at __webpack_require__ (saga.js:20)
    at eval (configureStore.js:8)
    at Object../js/stores/configureStore.js
```

`saga.js` is just simple.

```
export function* helloSaga(){
    console.log('Hello Sagas!');
}
```

And I have installed following module.

```
npm install @babel/polyfill --save
```

What is happening on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I get to use `@babel/polyfill` even if it is duplicated.

```
npm install @babel/polyfill --save
```

```
import '@babel/polyfill';

export function* helloSaga(){
    console.log('Hello Sagas!');
}
```

The error does not come out. It worked.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/280#issuecomment-291133023 , it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Check your babel configuration.

For @babel/preset-env check the `exclude` and `useBuiltIns` options:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#exclude

For @babel/preset-transform-runtime check the `regenerator` option:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#regenerator

Also @babel/polyfill has been deprecated in favor of directly using core-js and regenerator-runtime/runtime in babel 7.4:
https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/03/19/7.4.0#migration-from-core-js-2
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

Finally, try explicitly setting path to .babelrc in your babel-loader. I have a theory that babel is using different `.babelrc` name defaults to resolve it for some of its tasks.
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#configfile or
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#extends

Comment: my configuration for `babel.rc` is `{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/react"
    ]
}`

Comment: I don't know what is properly settings. I still have same error.